angular17 SwUpdate versionUpdates detects new version only for one tab if app is opned in multiple brower tabs
I have an angular17 app in which I am subscribing versionUpdates of SwUpdate. But If I have opened app in multiple tabs of browser then it detects new version availablity only for one tab and for all other tabs it says 'no new version detected'.
I need to show a notification in all open tabs for the app if there is new version of app is available. How can I achieve it? Please help, thanks in advance.
